# IE9 Form submits after mutiple click

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple HTML form that is not submitting in IE9. It works WELL in Chrome, FF, and IE10.

**Steps**:

1. Click on "Add Files" button
2. Add multiple files.
3. Follow step 1 and step 2 (twice)
4. Click Submit

If you click "Submit" it will load same page.

It's working on Chrome, FF and IE10. But in IE9 we need to click "Submit" button multiple times based on how many times we  clicked "Add Files" button.

Anyone can help me to identify where is wrong ?
Here is the form:

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/sreedharprabhuu/BxfQG/2/)

Code:

Form:

```
<form id="edit-object-form" name="multipleUpload" class="main-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="button" id="add-file-field" name="add" value="Add Files" />
                <div id="InputsWrapper"></div>
            <input type="submit" class="regular-btn-red submit_button" value="Submit Query" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
var InputsWrapper   = $("#InputsWrapper"); //Input file wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#add-file-field"); //Add button ID

var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of input file added

// Add Browse button
$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box <label for="myFile">** My Label **</label><br/>
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<input class="custom_input" type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="multiUpload'+FieldCount+'">');
            document.getElementById("multiUpload"+FieldCount).click();
return false;
});
})(jQuery);
```